# Displaying a video on the left and a paragraph above a form on the right

Tags: html, css

I'm out of ideas here, but I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.  I want the video to float left and the paragraph above the contact form all to float right.  The paragraph is cooperating but the form is out there on it's own.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content- "best=" " junk=" " car=" " buyers=" "
in=" " austin"="">
        <meta name="author" content="Lucky">
        <title>ATX Junk Cars</title>
        <style>
            iframe {
                clear: left;
                float: left;
            }
            <p> {
                float: right;
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;
                float: right;
                padding-left: 50px;
                padding-top: 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

<h1> ATX Junk           Cars&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbs    p;

&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&n    bsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;




<hr size="2" width="100%"> </h1>

        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dNWh2w5VSn4" allowfullscreen="" width="700" frameborder="0" height="450"></iframe>
        <p>If you're ready to turn that old car in your driveway into cash, we want to hear from you. Tell us who you are, how we can reach you, and most important, tell us about that car. For the fastest response, call or send a text to 512-229-5424. If it's 2:00 in the morning or you just don't like phones, send us a message with the form below.</p>
        <br>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Contact Form</title>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #330000;
                color: ffcc00;
        </style>
        <style>
            label {
                display:block;
                margin-top:20px;
                letter-spacing:2px;
        </style>
        <style>
            /* Centre the page */
            .body {
                display:block;
                margin:0 auto;
                width:576px;
            }
            /* Centre the form within the page */
            form {
                margin:0 auto;
                width:459px;
            }
            /* Style the text boxes */
            input, textarea {
                width:439px;
                height:32px;
                background:#efefef;
                border:1px solid #dedede;
                padding:10px;
                margin-top:3px;
                font-size:0.9em;
                color:#3a3a3a;
            }
            textarea {
                height:213px;
                background:url(images/textarea-bg.jpg) right no-repeat #efefef;
            }
        </style>
        <header class="body"></header>
        <section class="body">
            <label>Who are you?</label>
            <input name="name" placeholder="Name">
            <label>How do we call you?</label>
            <input name="phone" placeholder="Phone number with area code" type="phone">
            <label>Do you have keys and a clear title?</label>
            <input name="keys" placeholder="Keys, title or both?" type="keys">
            <label>Does it start, run and drive?</label>
            <input name="runs" placeholder="Yes or no?" type="runs">
            <label>Anything not working on it?</label>
            <textarea name="problems" placeholder="Dents, check engine lights, broken things?"></textarea>
            <input id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit">
        </section>
        <footer class="body"></footer>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not dump your entire code into the question. Post only the minimum amount of code required to reproduce the problem (for example, meta tags, title tags etc are not really required here). Also, please format the code properly before posting as it improves readability. Formatting would be more easy if you use the Stack Snippets (click on the `<>` icon in the tool bar).

Answer (score 0):

Add  `style="float:right;"` as below:

```
 <section class="body" style="float:right;">
 <label>Who are you?</label>
 <!-- your form code -->
 </section>
```